# How to count Total Price in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have retail data from which I created retail dataframe

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/databricks/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/master/data/retail-data/all/online-retail-dataset.csv')

retail_df = spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get('online-retail-dataset.csv'), header=True, inferSchema=True)\
  .withColumn('OverallItems', struct('StockCode', 'Description', 'UnitPrice', 'Quantity', 'InvoiceDate','CustomerID', 'Country'))
```

then I created `retail_array` that has two columns `InvoiceNo` and `Items`

```
retail_array = retail_df.groupBy('InvoiceNo')\
  .agg(collect_list(col('OverallItems')).alias('Items'))
```

I want to count total price of invoice items and add to into items column in `retail_array`.

So far I have written this code:

```
transformer = lambda x: struct(x['UnitPrice'], x['Quantity'], x['UnitPrice'] * x['Quantity']).cast("struct<UnitPrice:double,Quantity:double,TotalPrice:double>")

TotalPrice_df = retail_array\
  .withColumn('TotalPrice', transform("items", transformer))

TotalPrice_df.show(truncate=False)
```

But with this code I`m adding to` retail_array`new column, but I want this new column to be part of items column in`retail_array`.
for one invoice item output is like:

```
--+
|InvoiceNo|Items|TotalPrice                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|536366   |[{22633, HAND WARMER UNION JACK, 1.85, 6, 12/1/2010 8:28, 17850, United Kingdom}, {22632, HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT, 1.85, 6, 12/1/2010 8:28, 17850, United Kingdom}]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |[{1.85, 6.0, 11.100000000000001}, {1.85, 6.0, 11.100000000000001}]
```

I want it count `11.100000000000001 + 11.100000000000001` and add it into items column with no extra column. Also for other invoice items there are sometimes more than two total price I want to add to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html) instead of `transform` function to calculate the total price like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

retail_array = retail_df.groupBy("InvoiceNo").agg(
    F.collect_list(F.col("OverallItems")).alias("Items")
).withColumn(
    "TotalPrice", 
    F.aggregate("items", F.lit(.0), lambda acc, x: acc + (x["Quantity"] * x["UnitPrice"]))
)
```

Note however that you can actually calculate this `TotalPrice` in the same aggregation when you collect the list of structs and thus avoid, additional calculations by iterating on array elements:

```
retail_array = retail_df.groupBy("InvoiceNo").agg(
    F.collect_list(F.col("OverallItems")).alias("Items"),
    F.sum(F.col("Quantity") * F.col("UnitPrice")).alias("TotalPrice")
)

retail_array.show(1)
#+---------+--------------------+------------------+
#|InvoiceNo|               Items|        TotalPrice|
#+---------+--------------------+------------------+
#|   536366|[{22633, HAND WAR...|22.200000000000003|
#+---------+--------------------+------------------+
```

---

> But with this code I'm adding to `retail_array` new column, but I want this new column to be part of items column in `retail_array`

Note sure I correctly understood this part. `Items` column is an array of structs, that does not make much sens to replicate the total price of an `InvoiceNo` in each
of its items.

That said, if you really want to do this, you can use `transform` after calculating the total price (step above):

```
result = retail_array.withColumn(
    "Items",
    F.transform("Items", lambda x: x.withField("TotalPrice", F.col("TotalPrice")))
).drop("TotalPrice")

result.show(1, False)

#+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|InvoiceNo|Items                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
#+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|536366   |[{22633, HAND WARMER UNION JACK, 1.85, 6, 12/1/2010 8:28, 17850, United Kingdom, 22.200000000000003}, {22632, HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT, 1.85, 6, 12/1/2010 8:28, 17850, United Kingdom, 22.200000000000003}]|
#+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```